# Getting extension vendors on board for MageStackDay

Tags: discussion, community

So for the next MageStackDay we wanted to involve extension vendors to help close questions. Both for there knowledge of the extensions they sell and the Magento knowledge they have they would be a great addition to the crew.

Participation of vendors in the community can some times be a bit tricky so to that end we've set up a couple of guidelines with a lot of help from several people.

Please share your opinions, thoughts etc with us for MageStackDay

---

*The Magento community puts a lot of effort in this platform to share knowledge and help each other. Any extension vendor adding to stack exchange must be willing to share their knowledge, they cannot use the forum as a place for marketing.*

*Remember, a lot of times you're talking to developers. We like to know what kind of code we put in our projects and are fully capable of solving some issues ourselves with a little help.
If your answer helped us this time, we'll be more inclined to buy your extensions next time.*

We encourage you to

- use your company name on stackexchange to show your presence and committment to the community
- offer specific advice if someone asks directly for help regarding
  your extension but please avoid long discussions. An exchange of
  email would be better in that case
- explicitly mention your free extension if it meets a particular need.
  Please do only link directly to the extension if the source is freely
  available
- mention that there's a paid extension available for a
  particular need. You may also give some help about implementation
  like a starting point or involved areas (shipping, quote,...) or
  which settings to use. Screenshots always help. Make sure the poster
  of the question has enough information to decide whether or not the
  extension is suitable for them.
- add value to a new answer if another vendor answered before mentioning only an extension name.

Please refrain from

- direct advertising/marketing on magento.stackexchange.com